# Get view from other layout not work

Tags: android

I'm trying change text from other layout.

Class java (normal .java)

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, false);
tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText("xxx"); // not work, and no error
```

I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean from other layout?  If the text view isn't in the layout, of course findViewById will fail.

Comment: Where do you use this code at? Adapter or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected.
The TextView `tv` will have the "xxx" value.
But the way you do it, it is not displayed on screen. You inflate a layout but you did not display it.

Maybe you should use `setContentView()` method.